# Q: How can I combine these two foreach?

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have a simple html dom query which read informations from a football fixtures source, and I loading also a json source.

Here is my full code:

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set("user_agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17");

    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $str = file_get_contents('general.json');

    $json = json_decode($str,true);


        $filename = "source.html";
        $html = file_get_html($filename);




    class matches {
        var $day;
        var $kickofftime;
            var $title;


        function matches ($day, $kickofftime, $tip){
                    $this->day=$day;
            $this->kickofftime=$kickofftime;
                    $this->title=$title;
            return $this;
        }
    }


    $i=0;

    $day=$html->find('h1',0);
    $day->plaintext;
    $day=str_replace("<h1>TODAY FOOTBALL FIXTURES: ","", $day);
    $day=str_replace("</h1>","", $day);
    $matchday = str_replace(array('MONDAY ', 'TUESDAY ', 'WEDNESDAY ', 'THURSDAY ', 'FRIDAY ',  'SATURDAY ',  'SUNDAY '), '', $day);
    $matchday=str_replace(" ","-", $matchday);
    $matchday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($matchday));

    foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) 




    {




        foreach ($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {





    $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[class=a11],td[class=a21]',0)->plaintext;
    $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
    $result=$matchesTR->find('td');


    echo $kodate;
    echo $result[6]->plaintext.'<br>' ; 


    $i++;


        }
            }

//Here is the 2nd foreach with the data of JSON source:

    foreach($json as $key => $value) {

    $value = json_decode($value, true);



    echo $value["country"] . ", " . $value["competition"] . "  " . $value["club"] . "<br>";
    }


    // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

    ?>
```

The current results from the simple html dom html source:

**2014-12-23 20:00:00 2-1 

2014-12-23 11:00:00 3-1 

2014-12-26 08:00:00 1-1**

The result from the JSON source:

**America Copa America Boca Juniors

Europe Bundesliga Hannover

Asia JLeague Nagoya**

I would like to combine these two results in one foreach and I would like to get this result:

**2014-12-23 20:00:00 2-1 America Copa America Boca Juniors

2014-12-23 11:00:00 3-1 Europe Bundesliga Hannover

2014-12-26 08:00:00 1-1 Asia JLeague Nagoya**

I hope that there is some expert who can help for me because I tried a lot of variation but without result. Many thanks!

Comment: You can use `for` loop right

Answer (score 0):

```
     $j=0; 
 $jsonDecodedArray=$json;  

 foreach($html->find('table.fixtures') as $matches) 
{




    foreach ($matches->find('tr[class=a1],tr[class=a2]') as $matchesTR) {





        $kickofftime=$matchesTR->find('td[class=a11],td[class=a21]',0)->plaintext;
        $kodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$matchday $kickofftime +1 hour"));
        $result=$matchesTR->find('td');


        echo $kodate;
        echo $result[6]->plaintext." "; 
        echo $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["country"] . ", " . $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["competition"] . "  " . $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["club"] . "<br>"; ;

        $i++;
        $j++;


    }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But why do you use a second json decode? It is instead of the first json decode?

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given - I got this error message at this row: $jsonDecodedArray=json_decode($json);

Comment: something is not ok with your code, because I got error message everytime. With my code there was no error

Comment: Thank you for help, but now it is an Illegal string offset error message at this row:        echo $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["country"] . ", " . $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["competition"] . "  " . $jsonDecodedArray[$j]["club"] . "<br>";

Comment: I already tried a lot of variation but without success. With 2 json decoding I got error about json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given, and if I remove one of the json_decode, then I got the same error message what I got after I used your code

Comment: my json file is in these format: ["{\"country\":\"America\",\"competition\":\"Copa America\",\"club\":\"BOCA JUNIORS\"}","{\"country\":\"Germany\",\"competition\":\"Bundesliga\",\"club\":\"HANNOVER\"}","{\"country\":\"Asia\",\"competition\":\"JLeague\",\"club\":\"NAGOYA\"}"]

Comment: but with my code I could print all elements without error

Comment: array(218) { [0]=> string(110) "{"country":"America","competition":"Copa America","club":"BOCA JUNIORS".....

Comment: With my code I can generate all parameters successful, I think my json source is not bad

Comment: I added var_dump($json); after the row :  $json = json_decode($str,true); and I got the message what I pasted. array(218) because there are a lot of array in the json, not just these 3 what I added to the code.

Comment: I tried to merge the codes 2-3 times, but everytime got the same error message.